# Modifying a jQuery (highlighttextarea) plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I have decided to abandon textarea and use contenteditable div instead. I am now using Mark.js. I will close the question once I have enough reputation.*

I am modifying a jQuery ([highlighttextarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzNw8.png)) plugin.

**TL DR I have added a title tag but on hover nothing happens.**

The plugin matches the words entered into a text box to words we enter into a "dictionary". If the word is found, it is highlighted. The variables used are words and color. So if a word is found, the background is colored as stated in the variable color (ie. `color: '0000ff', words: ['whale']` <- the word whale gets a blue background).

I have tried to add a title attribute, where you would hover over the highlighted word and it would output the color which is used -> `return <mark title="'+color+'"style="background-color:'+color+';">+encodedMatch+'</mark>';`

It didn't work. Any idea how I could resolve this? Any help would be welcome.

PS: I tried to push the highlighted area forward with `z-index` but it didn't help.

excerpt of the code

```
        // Encode text before inserting into <div> so that the textarea and
        // overlay don't get out if sync when the textarea contains something
        // HTML (e.g. "&amp;" or <foo>).
        text = htmlDecode(text);

        var matches = [];

        var wordColorMap = {}, 
          allWords = [];
        $.each(this.settings.words, function (color, words) {
          $.each(words, function (index, word) {
            wordColorMap[word] = color;
            allWords.push(word);
          });
        });

        var allWordsRe = allWords.map(function (word) {
          var wordsRe = htmlDecode(word);
          var re = '(' + that.spacer + wordsRe + that.spacer + ')';
          return re;
        }).join('|');
        var regex = new RegExp(allWordsRe, that.regParam);


        var wordMatches = text.match(regex);
        if (wordMatches) {
            //added title
          text = text.replace(regex, function(innerMatch, start, contents) {
            matches.push(innerMatch);
            var encodedMatch = innerMatch
              .replace(/[&"<>]/g, function (c) {
                return {
                  '&': "&amp;",
                  '"': "&quot;",
                  '<': "&lt;",
                  '>': "&gt;"
                }[c];
              });

            var color = wordColorMap[innerMatch];
            return '<mark style="background-color:'+ color +';">' + encodedMatch + '</mark>';
          });
        }
```

[image: hover does nothing]

Comment: I'd inspect the replaced HTML (by right-clicking the highlighted text and selecting Inspect Element) and see if the attribute you added is shown in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have inspected it (with F12 tool) and it shows that it has a title. but when I hover on the highlighted area nothing happens... Adding a picture for clerification.

Comment: Ah, okay, the tooltip might be getting blocked by the `textarea`, since maybe the text isn't really in the `textarea`, but rather in that `div`? You could try messing with the z-index on the `mark` elements just to see if that does anything...